# Laravel display user data in view using id

Tags: php, laravel, database

This is what i tried so far and its working fine buuut, i don`t want to display all data in details in a single view but only id and/or name for example. Then if the id is clicked it should redirect to user data in details.

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('tenderview');
}

 public function show()
{
 
    $dataa = Kind::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(8);
    return view('tenderview',['dataa'=>$dataa]);
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/tenderview', 'TenderViewController@index')->name('tenderview');
Route::get('tenderview', 'TenderViewController@show')->name('tenderview');
```

View:

```
@foreach($dataa as $dater)
    <h5 class="card-title"><b> {{$dater->id}}</b></h5>
    <p><b> {{$dater->name}}</b></p>
     @endforeach
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem, exactly? Are you asking how to create links, add routes for those links, add Controller methods for those routes, and views for the methods?  You've already done all of that right here, so ... what's the problem?  Did you try searching for some tutorials ane examples - there are so many, did they not help?

Comment: Thanks @Don`t Panic it`s been a week now looking for the solution, problem here is; I don`t want to show all data in view but show id and name which will act as a link to full details of data like->tittle, message, location and so forth...

Comment: You have two routes with the same url _and_ the same name? How is that supposed to work? One of your routes at least needs a parameter to know which model to show. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-parameters

Comment: I have been searching...asking questions here but all in vain.

Comment: @Brombeer could you please atleased show how...becouse talk is cheap. What i need is the solution if it`s there, not critics if u can help help or keep quite...I am asking this question becouse i am not perfect, i have been using those two routes and now i want to update. What`s wrong with you people/?...if u can`t help you come to the comments and critisize

Comment: "_could you please atleased show how_" Huh? I linked the documentation on how to add parameters to routes, is that not enough?

Comment: Any Laravel tutorial will show you these basics. The docs also help!  Put the user ID (or whatever it is) in a URL, add a route to it: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#required-parameters Add a controller method to handle that route, use route model binding to load the model from the ID automatically: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-model-binding And add a view just like the one you have  ...

Comment: Enough for what @Brommbeer/?...Oh i see, if that`s a solution why can`t you post it as a solution. Do you think i will come here and ask questions without reading the documentation. Keep that link to youself. Thanks for nothing.

Comment: Thanks @Don't Panic for your perfect suggestion

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hope this simple solution might solve your problem.

**Route**

```
Route::get('tenderview', 'TenderViewController@index');
Route::get('tenderview/{param}', 'TenderViewController@show');
```

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    return view('tenderview');
}

public function show($id)
{

    $records = Kind::Where('id', $id)->get();
    return view('tenderview',['records'=>$records]);
}
```

**View**

```
     @foreach($records as $record)
       <h5 class="card-title"><b> {{$record->id}}</b></h5>
       <p><b> {{$record->name}}</b></p>
     @endforeach
```

Comment: This is a poor answer.  1) Why would you `orderBy()` and `paginate()` a query which should return 1 result?  2) If you're using Laravel, why not use it properly - [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-model-binding) means you don't need a query at all.  3) The `index()` method does not return or show any records at all.

Comment: Is that ok now? I just show him how to add the parameter in his query. Thats all. Thanks for correcting me @Don'tPanic

Comment: You might be right @Don`t Panic. 1. I chose it becouse it was the most helpfull not perfect, 2. I read the documentation and tried those examples which did not solve my problem that is why i ended up here. 3. There is the difference between commenting and answering the question in here, your comment was usefull so what did u excpect/?...to mark your comment as a correct answer/?

Comment: Your answer deserves to be marked right @Karthik SWOT atleased now i know how to add the parameter in my query, rather than being redirected to the documentation which does not know my question in details.

Comment: @ Don`t Panic Stackoverflow accepted my question, you pointed out the problem in my post that it sounds unclear to you,  @Karthik SWOT tried to help still you pointed out the problem in his answer. I am always on the internet searching for this i just can`t find the correct way to implement it in my code. I read those documantations and tutorial articles but their answers can`t solve my problem even though they are correct. You sounded very clear and thanks for that but atleased show some snippets to show me what you are talking about else mind your own business becouse you are not helping.

Comment: @MohailaTlaba if it's solved, please mark it as right.

Comment: Still a poor answer. `if (!$id) {...` why/when would `$id` not be set? It's a required parameter. Why would you only `->pluck('id')`? Why is the `index` method still empty?

Comment: I didn't give those pluck methods somebody edited like that. Now I edited and fixed it.

Comment: @tejas-prajapati don't edit answers and add your own random code.  If you think you have a better solution, add it as an answer.  Edits are for fixing typos, formatting, etc, not randomly changing someone else's code and answer.